# Journey Builder Re-Entry Only After Exiting for One Product Only?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, entry-criteria

I want to send a dynamic email to customers that expressed interest to a product. And I want to accomplish the below:

If a contact shows interest in Product A, he will receive the journey email, then he will stay in the journey for another 3 months before exiting. Since I have set the journey setting to "Re-Entry Only After Exiting", the contact should be able to receive the email about Product A again, but only after 3 months later.

However, while the contact is in the journey for Product A, if he expressed interest in Product B, I want him to enter the same journey again and receive the same dynamic email for Product B, even though he is already in the same journey for Product A.

How should I achieve this?

In my data extension I used OrderID as the primary key (the Order object is customized to store data if the contact expressed interest in a product). The data extension also includes ContactID and ProductID.

I assume I can achieve what I want to do if the journey's entry setting to look at the OrderID? However, it seems to me that the re-entry setting is only able to look at ContactID?

Thanks!

Comment: What type of the data source are you using in the journey?

Comment: Why not set up two different journeys?

Comment: @DucLe I am using a data extension created by sql, and the data comes from Salescloud.

Comment: @zuzannamj I have around 50 products so I would prefer using a dynamic email in one journey

Comment: In that case look into Exclusion Script to avoid sending emails about product A based on when someone entered the journey

Comment: @zuzannamj Hmm... So I am guessing the exclusion script will be matching the OrderID and the data extension used will have a retention setting for 3 months, so that the contact can reenter after 3 months?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea - what if you create a contact DE, and use "Update Contact" activity in the journey, if that customer is interested in a specific product, update the contact by adding the product to field with comma separated values, so you can use that field for decision split to see if this product has been previously added, the only thing I am not sure is if update activity supports concatenate data binding variables with comma:

1. Create a contactProducts DE and setup as contact data in Contact Builder, use ContactID as Primary key, and have a field called `ProductsInterestedIn` as text
2. Create the journey, allow re-entry anytime
3. add a decision split, check Contact DE contactProducts > ProductsInterestedIn field, see if it contains `{{Event.DEAudience-blah."Product"}}` field - Not sure if engagement split supports data binding
4. if true, then exit the journey
5. if false, send the email
6. after sending the email, add a "update contact" activity and update the contact data DE > ProductsInterestedIn field with DE field value plus comma plus entry Product value `{{Contact.Attribute.DataExtension.ProductsInterestedIn}} + "," + {{Event.DEAudience-blah."Product"}}`  - Not sure if you can concatenate values with data binding expressions

so after a few updates, the field value may look like: `productA,productC,productB,productF`

I feel if this works, it can dynamically check if a product has already been used, and you don't have to create 50 different paths or journeys. But it really depends on if data bindings are supported in #3 and #6